# How to insert sorted data to another sql datatables?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I prescribed conditions for sorting data in the SQL table:

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Company',     field_value, NULL)) AS Company_name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = "name",    field_value, NULL)) AS User_Name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Email',      field_value, NULL)) AS Email,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Phone_number',      field_value, NULL)) AS Phone

FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

I have a table where the data is all in 2 rows. I wrote a query that translates the data from rows in columns. Now I have to copy the result to another table.
How can I do that?

Comment: There may be a language issue here. That data isn't sorted. It may help if you provided sample data and the results you want.

Comment: @Eric Brandt Yep. One second.
I have a table where the data is all in 2 rows. I wrote a query that translates the data from rows in columns. Now I have to copy the result to another table.

Comment: Please show us the table that you want to insert the data.INSERT INTO table2 SELECT submit_time,...FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time  would the easiest way to insert